# Python - creating same sender email/sender in Random email/conversation generator

Tags: python, json, email, generator

I'm super new to Python and just trying my hand at a random email generator.

I'm just using json files with datasets in them, so there may be a better way to do this.

I can get the script to work no problems, but I need some advice on something.  I want the senders email to be the same as the sign off name. 
I.E. david_jones@hotmail etc comes from Regards, David Jones. At the moment i've got it generating a separate random email, and separate sign off name.  I need to link the two. Everything else is ok at the moment.

Can anyone help me with a better way to do this? 
Code:

```
import json
import random

f = open("C:/Users/*/Desktop/Email.txt", "a")

sentfrom = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Send.json').read())
send = sentfrom [random.randint(0,4)]

carboncopy = "CC:"

receiver = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/To.json').read())
to = receiver[random.randint(0,4)]

datesent = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Date.json').read())
date = datesent[random.randint(0,4)]

subjects = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Subject.json').read())
subject = subjects[random.randint(0,4)]

greetings = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Greeting.json').read())
greeting= greetings[random.randint(0,4)]

firstsentence = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Sent1.json').read())
sent1 = firstsentence[random.randint(0,4)]

secondsentence = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Sent2.json').read())
sent2 = secondsentence[random.randint(0,4)]

thirdsentence = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Sent3.json').read())
sent3 = thirdsentence[random.randint(0,4)]

fourthsentence = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Sent4.json').read())
sent4 = fourthsentence[random.randint(0,4)]

farewell = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Goodbye.json').read())
goodbye = farewell[random.randint(0,4)]

regards = json.loads(open('C:/Users/*/Desktop/*/Scripts/Test/Sender.json').read())
salutation = regards[random.randint(0,4)]

conversation = send +'\n'+ to +'\n'+ carboncopy +'\n'+ date +'\n'+ subject +'\n'+ '\n' + greeting +', \n'+ '\n' + sent1 +'\n'+ '\n' + sent2 +'\n'+'\n'+ sent3 +'\n'+'\n'+ sent4 +'\n'+'\n'+ goodbye +'\n'+'\n'+ salutation

f.write(conversation)
f.close()
```

Thanks in advance,
Buzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `regards` is what contains the sign off name..

You want to first get rid of the sign off name, instead of `'Regards, John Doe'`, Have all of them be `'Regards', 'Best', 'Thanks!'` etc. maybe just create a list instead of reading it from json:

```
regards = ['Regards,', 'Best,', 'Thanks!' ...]
```

Assuming everyone's format in email is the same, i.e. `john_doe@whatever.com`, you can get the name from this:

```
my_name = to.split('@')[0].replace('_', ' ').title()
# my_name will be 'John Doe'
```

And then add `my_name` to the `conversation` after `salutation`.

Comment: Thanks that's awesome.  I had the email addresses in the json as "From : jason@hotmail.com" but I've adjusted this to just the mail and then in the py file i've added "From : " to the concatenate section.

Comment: On another note for this code, does you or anyone know how to make the output of a function into a string so I can concatenate it as per the other strings i've done above? I can post the code if needed.